# Strange resistor colours

Tags: resistors

Normally this kind of thing wouldn't pose the slightest problem for me, but I am just trying to decipher the colours on a resistor.

- Orange
- Orange
- Gold
- Gold
- Black

[image]

All the online tools tell me it's a 4-band 3.3Ω, but that ignores the 5th black band.

Yes, when I measure it it's 3.3Ω.

So how does the colour coding work for that then? Is it a 4-band with some mystery extra band? Or does that 5th band signify something special?

Comment: What do you get when you measure it?

Comment: D'oh - why didn't that obvious thing occur to me? Yes, it's 3.3Ω. And if someone else had asked this question I would have written the exact same comment.

Comment: I have edited the question to help save face...

Comment: are you sure that the black band isn't actually brown???

Comment: The 5th band signifies the right-hand end of the resistor. ;-) Usually it's more over the end cap than on the body. I have seen them made just as you describe. The left hand can never start with black (0\$\Omega\$ resistors excepted), so it's unambiguous.

Comment: Do you have a picture maybe? Just to know how it might look.

Comment: It's definitely black, and it could be as you say to identify the precision end. Pic added.

Comment: Majenko - welcome back - I've noticed the long absent famous name around again of late. Where have you been - logically or physically. What brings you back? Here to stay a while?  Welcome regardless !!!! :-). - Russell

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I have been hiding out on the Arduino.SE site. I am undecided which is more annoying - the shear lack of any form of intelligence of the Ardueenies, or the pedantry that you often get here.  I felt I needed to escape there before they dragged me down to the level of making Instructables...

Comment: Majenko - While all groups have their flavours, you'd probably find the Skeptics site "interesting". Answers which are factual and / or explained with "hard Science" appear to be anathema, whereas ability to cite N references in publications of unknown authority seems to add 'cred. Really factual answers may get not just closed, but deleted. Mind you, deletion for spurious "reasons" seems to be spreading of late :-).

Comment: LOL. Personally I'd prefer a cynicism site ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I finally found something that supports Spehro Pefhany's proposal. This is a common 4 band resistor.
The black band is there because both 3 and 4 band resistors aren't required to use gold and silver on the readings. Thus, some resistors can be read backwards (Yikes).

To solve this, the black band is put onto the resistor to tell which way it's supposed to be read. Later, this was replaced by deliberately spacing the bands, but it seems that some manufacturers still use the black band.

[image]

Comment: That's making sense now. So it is just purely for orientation. Well, it is a cheap Chinese component in a cheap Chinese counterfeit power supply...