# Purpose of this resistor?

Tags: resistors

So I am dismantling and ripping into a cheap Chinese counterfeit phone charger and revealing all that I see wrong with it. One thing I could do with some insight into though is the purpose of a resistor.

It is basically a 3.3Ω resistor which is in series with the mains (240V) input into the bridge rectifier:

[image]

What are they trying to achieve there?

(Mind, given the state of the rest of the circuit maybe even the designers don't know?)

Should it in fact have been a fuse?

Comment: What is the Issm rating of the bridge rectifier? This could be a surge current limiter to "protect" the bridge. Whether it's an adequate one is another matter. 35A * 3.3 ohms plus stray resistance isn't too far off 110V (arguably not 165V, nor 230VAC)

Comment: Was it marked 3.3 Ω or did you measure it? If you measured it could be a self-resetting fuse.

Comment: @BrianDrummond \$I_{FSM}\$ is 35A. It's an [MB6F](http://www.topdiode.com/pdf/MB2F-MB10F.pdf)

Comment: @Transistor Both: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/255091/strange-resistor-colours

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some resistors are designed so that they will fail open when they overheat.
An advantage of such resistors versus fuses is that when failure is a result
of an output short-circuit, the resistor will limit how much current will
pass in the time it takes to blow.  With 120V mains (170V peak) the peak
current would be about 50 amps, which is rather a lot, but is still much
less than would be able to pass through a "normal" fuse.

Comment: Aha, so it's basically being used as a slow-blow fuse with built in current limiting. Doesn't that present a fire hazard at all?

Comment: You did say "cheap Chinese counterfeit phone charger". It's not like safety is high on their list of priorities.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams You should see the PCB layout and soldering... Shocking (potentially literally...) https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/30/dangers-of-counterfeit-power-supplies/

Comment: This is a 240V supply. The peak current would be ~100A, which means if it shorted there would be a 45KW furnace inside the power supply... Surely the MCB would normally blow before the "fuse" melted its way through the case...

Comment: I'd not want to specify a resistor here unless there was an "all-fire" specification for it. Something like, "100 Joules delivered in 20ms" guarantees an "open" to occur.

Comment: I am thinking this resistor might be why so many shoddy Chinese chargers cause house fires...

Comment: +1 for super. @Majenko Pretty nasty, but I've seen even worse in the $1 fake iPhone chargers. Usually the touch screen problem is from a missing Y cap, but that appears to have it. Dangerous in any case.

Comment: @Majenko: Given the thermal mass of the resistor, it wouldn't be 45KW for very long; the critical question is what happens when the resistor does overheat as it certainly would.  I'm somewhat puzzled by why the resistor has such a low value since a 3300 ohm resistor would dissipate 0.03 watt at 10mA but would limit peak fault currents to a much more tolerable ~1A.  That would still be 200W until something failed, but one could be more assured that the fault power would be confined to the resistor.

Comment: A fusible resistor is often indicated by markings on the printed wiring board (because it is safety-critical).   This could be such a fuse, in which case a fuse+resistor hybrid symbol is sometimes used.

Answer (score 0):

it is for current limit to replace NTC+fuse. It is a common design for 5watts charger. The resistance will effect efficient, the value will be adjusted by different design. The common value could be 3.3/5.1/8.2/10 ohm.

the resistor name Fusible wirewound resistor.